# How to update docker images

Tags: python, image, docker

Let's say I have a below Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/pyton3

import time
while(True):
      print("Hello World")
      time.sleep(1)
```

Using above Python code I have created a docker image `pythondocker` by using a dockerfile. Now dockerfile contains a lots of packages which it needs to install first and then build an image. After the image is build, I can easily start/stop the container.

Now my question is, for example, I have made few changes to my Python code and I want to update docker image `pythondocker` with the new changes. How can I achieve this.? One way is to fisrt stop the container, then delete the image and again build it. But building an image again will take some time as it will again install all the packages. Is there any way I can stop the image instead of deleting it and then apply the changes to the current image or may be build the image but without installing the packages/dependencies which are mentioned in dockerfile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Dockerfile may look like this:

```
FROM python:2

RUN apt-get install libxxx
ADD requirememts.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

ADD main.py /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN pip install -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

You can simply run `docker build -t some_tag .`. Only lines below `ADD main.py /usr/src/app` will be re-installed / upgraded, and lines above are installed only once when you build the image for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

You should build your docker images by using **docker-compose** file.

Just follow any tutorial for how to use docker-compose.

and then without any manually deletion you can re-build and re-run all images by using below commands.

**Build all Images**

```
docker-compose build
```

**Build and run all containers**

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I have listed some daily useful commands for docker, have a look
https://rohanjmohite.wordpress.com/2017/08/04/docker-daily-useful-commands/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your Dockerfile is layered, you can simply build the image again (without deleting it). It will use the cache whenever possible.

Docker will use the cache when the files in the layer (line) did not change and the preceding layers (lines) did not change as well. So if your python code sits at the bottom of your Dockerfile, it should only build this layer. Which should be fast.

After that you can run your image again.